# XCODE - SQL Dates

Tags: sql, xcode, date

I am trying to update my SQL DB when the the date has expired (i.e is less than now)
I have this lovely bit of SQL code

```
Update Notifications 
SET Active = 'N' 
where CAST(SetDate AS DATE) <= CAST('2012-08-23 11:19:00 +0000' AS DATE)
```

But it updates all the records (even if the date is not less than now)

I have also tried

```
Update Notifications 
SET Active = 'N' 
where CAST(SetDate AS DATE) < CAST('2012-08-23 11:19:00 +0000' AS DATE)
```

But this dosent affect any rows.

I guess I have something a little confused??

Any help???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see anything odd about the code, except for this line:

```
CAST('2012-08-23 11:19:00 +0000' AS DATE)
```

If you are using `CAST()` to change it to the date, then there is no need to pass in the time portion of the value.

You did not provide the full table schema but one thing to consider is using a `bit` field for the `Y/N` values.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba453/1) with the code working

```
Update Notifications 
SET Active = 'N' 
where CAST(SetDate AS DATE) <= CAST('2012-08-23' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have confused is types in SQL. I don't know what database you are using, but it probably has types for boolean (or int) and date. Storing booleans and dates as strings is very inefficient. For example, even if your example did work it would have to scan the entire database and cast each value in order to compare it.

The clue to the error is the `<` vs `<=`. This hints at the values being equal. If the cast fails on both sides, and returns the default value of zero, then then will be equal.

You should change your schema to use the correct types, then your query will work.